# How to re-compile an ACPI table on Linux?

Tags: linux, gnu, acpi

Simple question, I found the following ACPI table online:

```
/*
 * Intel ACPI Component Architecture
 * AML/ASL+ Disassembler version 20190509 (64-bit version)
 * Copyright (c) 2000 - 2019 Intel Corporation
 * 
 * Disassembling to symbolic ASL+ operators
 *
 * Disassembly of application.bin, Mon Dec 16 18:14:02 2019
 *
 * Original Table Header:
 *     Signature        "SSDT"
 *     Length           0x000000A1 (161)
 *     Revision         0x01
 *     Checksum         0xF4
 *     OEM ID           "BOCHS"
 *     OEM Table ID     "BXPCSSDT"
 *     OEM Revision     0x00000001 (1)
 *     Compiler ID      "INTL"
 *     Compiler Version 0x20191018 (538513432)
 */
DefinitionBlock ("", "SSDT", 1, "BOCHS", "BXPCSSDT", 0x00000001)
{
    External (_SB_.PCI0, DeviceObj)

    Scope (_SB.PCI0)
    {
        Device (BAT0)
        {
            Name (_HID, EisaId ("PNP0C0A") /* Control Method Battery */)  // _HID: Hardware ID
            Name (_UID, Zero)  // _UID: Unique ID
            Method (_STA, 0, NotSerialized)  // _STA: Status
            {
                Return (0x1F)
            }

            Method (_BIF, 0, NotSerialized)  // _BIF: Battery Information
            {
                Return (Package (0x0D)
                {
                    One, 
                    0x1770, 
                    0x1770, 
                    One, 
                    0x39D0, 
                    0x0258, 
                    0x012C, 
                    0x3C, 
                    0x3C, 
                    "", 
                    "", 
                    "LION", 
                    ""
                })
            }

            Method (_BST, 0, NotSerialized)  // _BST: Battery Status
            {
                Return (Package (0x04)
                {
                    Zero, 
                    Zero, 
                    0x1770, 
                    0x39D0
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I'm wondering how I could recompile it with standard Linux tools. What language is it even written in?
I know how to compile C or C++, but this seems to be something else that I haven't seen before.

Comment: You need to have ACPICA tools to be installed. Usually all modern distributions provide a corresponding package. In such package you will find `iasl` which translates to or disassembles from AML (ACPI Machine Language) respectively from / to ASL (ACPI Source Language) as above. The command to compile and use the SSDT is provided in the documentation: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/acpi/ssdt-overlays.html (Tell me if I need to make it an answer)

Comment: Awesome, so I just need to compile my ASL into ASM by running `iasl my-code.asl` if I understand correctly. I'll give that a try, thank you!